# Django logging: logger doesnt write to file

Tags: python, django, logging

I'm trying to write to a logger in Django.  I've got at the beginning of the `views.py` file:

```
import logging
logger = logging.getLogger('wm')
```

and later make calls to

```
logger.debug('message')
```

In my `settings.py` file, I have defined

```
LOGGING = {
    'formatters': {
        'medium': {
            'format': '[%(username)s] %(levelname)s %(asctime)s: %(message)s'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'wmlogfile': {
            'class': 'logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django/wm.log',
            'level':'DEBUG',
            'maxBytes': 1024*1024, # 5 MB
            'backupCount': 5,
            'formatter': 'medium',
        },

    },
    'loggers': {
        'wm': {
            'handlers': ['wmlogfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': False,
        }
    }
}
```

At first, I was getting 500 errors because the file didn't exist, and then because the permission was denied.  I manually created the file and set the permissions to 777, and the app runs, but I get no output in the log file.

What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Try setting `disable_existing_loggers` to `False` as per the example [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/logging/#examples).